# Integration factor differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the equation: $$2y\:\mathrm{d}x- (\ln{y}+2x-1)\:\mathrm{d}y=0$$

I have to solve this.So,I noticed that $\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$ is different from $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}$ so I have to apply the integrating factor. $P$ here is $2y\:\mathrm{d}x$ and $Q$ is $\ln{y}+ 2x-1$

So: $$\frac{1}{Q}\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}\right)= \left[\frac{1}{\ln{y}+2x-1}\right] \times(2-2) =0$$

This cant be zero because I have to find the integrating factor using this so where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Note that if we set $M(x,y)=2y,~~N(x,y)=-\ln x-2x+1$ then $M_y-N_x=4$. So $$\mu(y)=\exp\left(\int\frac{4}{2y}dy\right)$$

Comment: But Q(x) is lny+2x-1 not 2y :/

Comment: @sdfsfd: Isn't there a minus befor the second parentheses?

Comment: You've been on a roll today!

Comment: @amWhy: Hello my dear friend. :-^)

Comment: Hello, my friend! How are you?

Comment: Good Amy and by seeing you it gets better.:) I collected all I have done to give them to my supervisor. I wanna tell him, that he wasted my time by giving me a wrong guess. I could find a sequences of $2^n$'s which violet his conjecture.